# How to set up a target grid for kriging in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, gstat

I've read the exellent tutorial-blog post on Kriging in R by Dr. Wilke - found here:https://swilke-geoscience.net/post/2020-09-10-kriging_with_r/kriging/

Applying this step by step on my data csv-file, Irun into trouble defining my target grid.

My code:

```
kerpensample <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\49151\\Desktop\\datasample.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")
str(data)
head(data)

ggplot(
  data = kerpensample,
  mapping = aes(x = X, y =Y, color = Z)
) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_viridis_b() +
  theme_classic()
  

st_crs(kerpensample)

utm32nCRS <- st_crs(kerpensample)
class(utm32nCRS)

kerpensample_sf <-st_as_sf(kerpensample, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = utm32nCRS) %>% 
  cbind(st_coordinates(.))

v_emp_OK <- gstat::variogram(
  Z~1,
  as(kerpensample_sf, "Spatial")
  )

plot(v_emp_OK)

v_mod_OK <- automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(kerpensample_sf, "Spatial"))$var_model
plot(automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(kerpensample_sf, "Spatial")))

grd_100_sf <- kerpen_sf %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_make_grid(
    cellsize = c(100, 100), # 100m pixel size
    what = "centers"
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))


gridded(grd_100_sp) <- TRUE             
grd_100_sp <- as(grd_100_sp, "SpatialPixels")
```

Here are the errors I get :

```
Error in st_bbox(.) : object 'kerpernsample_sf' not found
> 
> # Step 2: making our grid work for gstat
> gridded(grd_100_sp) <- TRUE             
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  cannot derive grid parameters from a single point!
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  cell size from constant coordinate 1 possibly taken from other coordinate
2: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  cell size from constant coordinate 2 possibly taken from other coordinate
> grd_100_sp <- as(grd_100_sp, "SpatialPixels")
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  cannot derive grid parameters from a single point!
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  cell size from constant coordinate 1 possibly taken from other coordinate
2: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  cell size from constant coordinate 2 possibly taken from other coordinate
```

I also tried making my own with spsample but this doesn't work too:

```
> samp = sp::spsample(x = kerpensample_sf, n = 1000, type = "random")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spsample’ for signature ‘"sf"’
```

But problem seems easier to fix, but I don't know how to transform my data into this spdf file it needs to be.

**Edit**: here is a small sample of my data : https://ufile.io/8qim4bku

-----EDIT-----

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
require(gstat)

setwd("C:/Users/49151/Desktop")

#import data
data <- read.csv("krigrtest.csv")

head(data)

hist(data$Z, breaks = 20, xlab = "subsidence rates (mm/year)", main = "Histogram of subsidence at Kreuz Kerpen")
summary(data$Z)

#if skewed: 
#data$Z.1 <- log10(data$Z)
#hist(data$Z.1, breaks = 10, xlab = "subsidence rates (mm/year)", main = "Histogram of subsidence at Kreuz Kerpen")

#convert data
coordinates(data) <- c("X", "Y")
#assigning projection
proj4string(data) <-CRS("+init=epsg:32632")

#make bubble plot:

library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data1 <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 4326)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = data1, aes(size = Z, fill = Z), shape = 21, alpha = 0.9)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")+
  theme_bw()


#Variogram

library(automap)

v_mod_OK <- automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(data1, "Spatial"))$var_model
plot(automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(data1, "Spatial")))

#grid
grid = st_as_stars(st_bbox(st_buffer(kerpensample_sf, 0.001)))
grid = st_as_sf(grid)

#interpolation
OK <- krige( Z~1, as(data1, "Spatial"), grid, model = v_mod_OK)

ggplot(i, aes(x = "X", y = "Y", col =var1.pred)) + geom_point()
```

here is the krigrtest-file: https://ufile.io/28byderz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template raster for the interpolation using the `raster` or `stars` packages. Here is a reproducible example with your data, using function `stars::st_as_stars`:

```r
library(sf)
library(gstat)
library(automap)
library(stars)

# Read CSV
kerpensample = read.csv("datasample.csv")

# To 'sf'
kerpensample_sf = st_as_sf(kerpensample, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 32632)

# Variogram model
v_mod_OK = autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(kerpensample_sf, "Spatial"))$var_model

# Create grid
grid = st_as_stars(st_bbox(st_buffer(kerpensample_sf, 0.001)))

# Interpolation model
g = gstat(formula = Z~1, model = v_mod_OK, data = kerpensample_sf)

# Interpolate
z = predict(g, grid)

# Plot
plot(z, col = hcl.colors(12, "Spectral"), reset = FALSE)
plot(st_geometry(kerpensample_sf), add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(kerpensample_sf), as.character(round(kerpensample_sf$Z, 1)), pos = 3, add = TRUE)
```

The last three expressions display the interpolated surface as follows:

[image: interpolation_result]

Comment: using kriging with stars throws an error at me: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spplot’ for signature ‘"stars"’  code: OK <- krige(
  Z~1,
  as(kerpensample_sf, "Spatial"),
  grid, 
  model = v_mod_OK

Comment: For me the expression `OK <- krige( Z~1, as(kerpensample_sf, "Spatial"), grid, model = v_mod_OK)` works fine, without errors. If you can please post a complete reproducible example that results in the error for you I'll be happy to try and check.

Comment: ok got it to work. however the plot is still not what I need, unfortunately. I will ask a new question as it is a diffrent topic.

Comment: I have a follow-up question after I applied it on my actual datasets(consisting of 600 and 140 points each stored in csv): if I convert the stars object back to a sf(which I need it to be) I get a grid of 65.000 obsvervation, which a) puts the computation time to a few hours and b) the results are definetly not right. I'll make an edit here and include the complete code.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the `stars` object to `sf`? This is rarely the best approach. If you can elaborate what are you trying to do, will try to advice about a different approach